# Getting integer value instead of string out of database in android

Tags: java, android, database, android-cursor

The concept: I'm trying to implement 'add to favourites' feature in my app. So in one activity, I have many pages(children of ViewPager) with heart image. By clicking that image a string from an array list get inserted into the table of the database. In the second activity, I'm trying to retrieve that value from that table's column and setting it to a TextView.

The problem: I'm getting some long number as text instead of the string.

```
2131165458
```

An ArrayList of String:

```
  final ArrayList<String> array= new ArrayList<>();
    array.add(getString(R.string.one_1));
    array.add(getString(R.string.one_2));
    array.add(getString(R.string.one_3));
```

Heart image with onClickListener:

```
final ImageView favourite = (ImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.favourite);
favourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
  boolean hasInserted = myDB.hasInserted(array.get(position));
                if (hasInserted) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "DATA INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
  }
    });
```

Here's the SqliteOpenHelper:

```
class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Favourites_Database";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Favourites";
//private static final String COL_1 = "ID";
private static final String COL_2 = "Favourites";

 DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 3);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Favourite TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

 boolean hasInserted(String favourites) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, favourites);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
     return  (result != -1);
}

 Cursor showData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
}
```

}

In the second activity, trying to retrieve col_2 values:

```
 myDb = new DBHelper(this);
    Cursor data = myDb.showData();
  if(data.moveToFirst()) {
          do {
              String res = data.getString(1);
              textView.setText(res);
              textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
          }while (data.moveToNext());
      }
```

Thanks guys in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your create table statement the second column is `Favourite`

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + "(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Favourite TEXT)");
```

but in your `hasInserted()` method you have used `contentValues.put(COL_2, favourites)` where `COL_2` value is `Favourites` which is different.

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(COL_2, favourites);
```

**#.** Use same column `Favourite` for `creating` table and `querying` data from table `Favourites`.

**Update your code as below:**

```
.......
...............

private static final String COL_2 = "Favourite";

DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 3);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Favourite TEXT)");
}

........
..................
```

**Finally, `Uninstall` and `Re-Install` your application.**

Comment: Thanks so much FAT! I remember now, I changed it after putting the value.